# Perl: How to access an array thats inside of 3 hashes passed to subroutine by reference

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash, dereference

I have a code that is something like this:

```
foreach $item (@total_data)
{
    setinfo($item);
} # @total_data contains an array of references to hashes (\%hash1 ... \%hashN)
```

In the subrutine goes something like this:

```
sub setinfo
{

    my ($argument) = @_;

    my $i = 0;


    #inside original hash $argument{"data"}{"fulldraw"} there is an [array]
    #that  contains numbers of the form XYYZ and I want to split them into
    #the following pairs XY YY YZ but that code works ok#

    foreach $item (${$argument{"data"}{"fulldraw"}})
    {
        my $match;
        my $matchedstr;

        if ($item =~ /^\d{4}$/) 
        { 

                          ...
        }
        else
        {
            print STDERR "DISCARDED: $item\n";
        }
    }


}
```

I know I am probably making the mistake in how I am dereferencing it, but couldn't figure it out with all the articles I've read on the internet.

Thanks!

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{ ... } # dereference
```

Maybe $argument is a hashref; you need to use

```
foreach $item (@{ $argument->{data}->{fulldraw} })
```

Comment: Hi, I am still trying, and some minutes ago I came up with:

foreach $item (@{$$argument{"data"}{"fulldraw"}})

and this worked right. What you say is the same?

Comment: It worked the same. Now I have another question if I can ask you.

Comment: @SJPRO same. $argument is a hashref, not hash, so need to dereference or use another syntax.

Comment: @SJPRO, `$$argument{"data"}` is a less readable way of writing `$argument->{"data"}`, which is a less readable way of writing `$argument->{data}`

Answer (score 1):

Just use dereference `@{ ... }`:

```
foreach $item (@{ $argument->{data}{fulldraw} })
```

You can use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) to visualize complex structures:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($argument);
```

Comment: Hi, doesn't work, it doesn't even execute the foreach loop.

Comment: Fixed. You were accessing the hash `%argument` rather than the hash referenced by `$argument`.